# Wrappanel in ItemsControl.ItemsPanel throws XamlParseException

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, itemscontrol, wrappanel

In my wp8 app I show some content (images for example). I use LongListSelector, and in each LLS's item have ItemsControl with collection of images. I want to show two images in one line, so I use a wrappanel. But it throws XamlParseException in line `InitializeComponent()` in usercontrol's page. Without wrappanel all works fine. Here the code

```
            <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Vkontakte.Attachments.Photos}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Height="100" Width="100" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Image Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Src}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

**Maybe problem is in the case, that `ItemsControl` is in the `StackPanel`?**

Comment: And the exception is?  And the inner exception?  Stacktrace?  Without, all we can do is guess...either 1. your xmlns for toolkit is malformed 2. the assembly defined within the namespace is not found 3. the version loaded into the designer is different than the one delivered to the bin folder 4. the constructor of the WrapPanel is throwing an exception.  First three can be discovered by turning on fusion binding and carefully examining what happens at runtime, the last by attaching a second instance of visual studio to the first with a breakpoint in the constructor for the WrapPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The exception my be thrown due to your ItemsSource binding. If Vkontakte is not an object on your datacontext then you may need to take a look at what you are binding to. It needs to be a collection of some kind of object.

Comment: It might still be true. If it is null, it might have unexpected behavior.